# Strapi: How to populate data two levels deep?

Tags: rest, strapi

I want to populate data two levels deep. Therefore I wrote the following:

```
let homepage = qs.stringify({
    populate: '*',
  },{
    encodeValuesOnly: true, // prettify URL
  });
```

This returns the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
          },
          "att1": {
          },
          "att2": {
          },
          "att3": {
          },
          "att4": [],
          "Projekte": {
          }
      }
  },
  "meta": {}
}
```

The nested Object “Projekte” now does contain an image. How can I access it?

Comment: Your question makes no sense, because `qs.stringify` does not return json.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the fields you want to populate. In your case :

```js
let homepage = qs.stringify({
    populate: 'Projekte',
  },{
    encodeValuesOnly: true, // prettify URL
  });
```